# Existing keypair is not in AWS Cloudflormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I wanted to create a EC2 instance with airflow (using cloud formation) as mentioned in this tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-a-concurrent-data-orchestration-pipeline-using-amazon-emr-and-apache-livy/

I already have a key pair created, but it is not visible to create a stack in cloud formation. What am I missing here ?

Attached screenshot for reference

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your key pair and the stack which you want to create are in **different regions**. Both key pairs and stacks are regional, thus they must be in the same region.